# Is bumping a questions for views wrong?

Tags: discussion

I have edited a question many times, in order to get more views. Now it has become locked because I have edited it too many times

Is it wrong to edit or put up bounties to refresh a question **in order to get more people to see it**?

Comment: One of the selectable bounty reasons is specifically because you think it deserves more attention.

Comment: Upvoted because "is bumping a question for views wrong?" is a legitimate question, although the answer should be somewhat obvious: it's called "edit" not "draw more attention". Bounties to draw more attention are 100% okay. Making trivial edits just to "bump" your post is not.

Comment: Why would you do that? Sounds non-value added and a waste of time to me. Is the question so praiseworthy that it must be seen by all multiple times? If you just want a badge, ask a few good questions and make good answers and the badges (and rep) will come as a natural byproduct.

Answer (score 9):

I'll see if I can pull up the relevant Meta posts (short version: if you do it once or twice, it's OK; if your edits materially improve the question, it's OK; but if you do it constantly JUST to get the views with irrelevant edits, you're at best abusing the system).

As a matter of fact, the old (now removed) rule that a post automatically becomes Community Wiki after N edits, was in part specifically designed to prevent such abuse.

Some relevant reads:

- [Purposeful Question Bumping: Abuse or feature?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4397/purposeful-question-bumping-abuse-or-feature)
- [Is it fair to edit a question I've answered to bump it to the top of the questions list?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84732/is-it-fair-to-edit-a-question-ive-answered-to-bump-it-to-the-top-of-the-questio)

---

However, if you're truly interested in raising the views, bumping the question with edits is the **least** efficient way to edit it, leaving aside whether it's OK or not.

Instead, you should make it go "viral", or at least, popularize it outside SE by posting links to it where people who might be interested in such content will see the link and come read - reddit, your blog, twitter, facebook, etc...

That is not simplyt within the site rules - it is actively encouraged by SE, as evidenced by 3 badges rewarded specifically for this (Announcer, Booster and Publicist: "Shared a link to a question that was visited by 25/300/1000 unique IP addresses").

This both helps you (you get badges for visits, and for good posts, upvotes and badges from visitors) AND the site (which gets new visitors some of which will hopefully stay).

Oh, and it works pretty well. I managed to reddit myself to the 1000 visit badge on SFF, and 300 visit badge on StackOverflow - given that I'm active in low-interest low-traffic Perl tag, that's pretty darn good.

Answer (score 3):

As to the second part of your question;

Yes, putting a bounty on your question is an excellent way to garner more attention for it. The larger the bounty, usually the greater the level of attention it will receive.

You might also want to ensure that you post *useful or constructively critical* comments on any answers you receive and use those as a jumping-off point for your own research.

Comment: The question in question has one answer, which is upvoted and accepted.  It's not an issue of there not being a good answer.

Comment: @Keen - I presume there's nothing to stop him un-accepting it, then adding a bounty.

Comment: The OP posted a now-deleted comment indicating they were doing this purely for the bump in views.

Answer (score 1):

**Has the question already been answered?**

If the answer to this is "yes" (and if it's the one I think it is, then the answer **is** "yes"), then it's served it's purpose.  It was asked, it was answered, so let it drift down the page.  You need to consider what your purpose in wanting more people to see it really is, because **Stack Exchange is not a popularity contest**.  By continually bumping such a question up to the top, you're taking up a slot on the home page that **might otherwise have been used by a different, unanswered question**.  Why should your question be so awesome that it can do that?  This behaviour just seems rude and selfish to me.

If the answer is "no" then use the available tools (such as bounties) for attracting more attention to it.  Or consider that maybe the reason why it wasn't asnwered was because it's genuinely unanswerable, or it just didn't interest people enough.  *That's* where continued edits *are* useful, but they need to be *targetted* at resolving a *specific* problem with the question, rather than just a means of jumping up and down shouting "Hey! Look at me! Over here! Some attention please!"

Answer (score 1):

Don't just bump questions for the sake of it, or to game the system.  Edits are supposed to be used to ['substantially improve'](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit) posts.  I noticed your frequent bumps to the question in question, and looked over its history.

1. It had been asked back in February.
2. It received an objectively thorough answer in February, *which you replied to with a 'thanks'*.  It was also accepted.
3. In early April, you put a bounty on it, which you then awarded to the one, accepted answer.  The reason for this bounty was 'draw attention'.
4. You added some tags and some trivia to the question in mid-April.
5. In early May, you added more tags, and started another bounty, which is when it caught my notice.  I saw a comment on the question from another user that seemed off, like it was referring to a deleted comment.  So I looked at the deleted comments on the post, and saw your post stating that you're doing all this to get a badge for 2500 views.
6. I then check to see the reasons posts should be locked, as I know this sort of shenanigans is discouraged for the purpose of gaining reputation.  There's a [handy FAQ post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22229/158781) that addresses that:

> Some examples of when a post might be locked include:
>
> - A question or answer where repeated voting or editing is happening in a way which attempts to game, hack, or otherwise abuse the system.

This matched the 'gaming the system' description, so I locked the post and removed the bounty.  I put a comment on the post telling you to knock it off.

---

Bounties are to be used to help get an answer to an unanswered (or unsatisfactorily-answered) question, or to reward exceptional answers.  The 'draw attention' bounty reason refers to **getting better answers**, not 'I want this to get more views'.

---

Go all out editing posts to make substantial improvements, that's why editing is there.  Use bounties to improve the quality/content of answers, and to also reward good ones.  But just gaming the site so you get more rep/badges/whatever isn't acceptable, and will be moderated.

If people abuse the system this way, then as [Jimmy Shelter said](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3605/1027), it clogs the 'active' feed on `/questions` with stuff that doesn't need attention, and makes it harder for people to actually get help on other questions.  As [DVK said](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3603/1027), this isn't even an effective way to get this badge.  Post a link to it on twitter, or reddit, or other social sites where people will find it interesting.  You'll earn the badge in no time.